# Flash Builder 4 Settings

Tags: apache-flex, flash, settings, flexbuilder, flash-builder

i'm slowly making my way over to Flash Builder from doing all of my programming in Flash Professional.

it's not an easy transition since things i've taken for granted in Flash Professional are completely different in Flash Builder.

first, FB4 will always automatically convert my function (even pasted functions) to look like this:

```
private var myFunction(...parameters):void
{
     //my code
}
```

but i'd like it to automatically write it like this:

```
private var myFunction(...parameters):void
     {
     //my code
     }
```

finally, the other thing that i'm really having a hard time with is the code hinting.  in Flash Builder i have to press enter/return on the keyboard to accept the code hint, while in Flash Professional i press tab to accept.

is it possible to change these settings in Flash Builder to match those i'm use to in Flash Professional?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  I suspect the keypress/code hinting issue is inherited from Eclipse.  The code formatting, there are some settings in global preferences, but I don't see anything related to formatting of pasted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options related to indentation in the Preference panel, but not related to your issue. And I'm not aware of doing that neither in Intellij Flex plugin.

Also you cannot change the code hinting behavior. You can request an enhancement, btw.